# How do I check a column that contains a string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

currently I've been using this:

```
SELECT * FROM `meow` WHERE profile LIKE '%$username%'
```

But the problem I'm facing is if someone puts the letters 'a' it will pull everything that contains a and that's a bit of a security risk on my end, How do i search just 1 column to see if it matches $username exactly? not the whole table?

Comment: If you don't want to pull everything for the match, then simply remove `LIKE` with `=`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`meow\` WHERE \`profile\` = '$username'`

Comment: okay guys, thank you all for your help.. because what i was storing in the db was a link. that made things complicated, so i've made a function to explode the chars to get exactly what i need, then insert it into the database so i can search for exact values :)

Answer (score 2):

For exact string matching you should the `=` operator instead of the `like` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM `meow` WHERE profile = '$username'
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using string concatenation to build your query. It's evil. Instead use mysqli or pdo and use prepared statements.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb', 'your_username', 'your_password');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `meow` WHERE profile = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Also, use equality, instead of `like`, if you wish to check for exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using like use equal to

try this :

```
 SELECT * FROM meow WHERE profile = '$username'
```

Comment: Yeah but i forgot to mention, the string im after is in a link! like http://example.com/fpix?$username and $username.example.com its not just $username it has a bunch of stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
"SELECT * FROM `meow` WHERE profile LIKE '$username'"
```

for exact match.